# MS Access using function on onclick event of button

Tags: ms-access

I have below function on form:

```
Function StringsHaveAMatchingCharacter(String1 As Variant, String2 As Variant) As Boolean

     ' Return True if the two strings have at least one character in common;
     ' otherwise return False.

     Dim lngX As Long

     If IsNull(String1) Or IsNull(String2) Then
         ' No point checking for a match.
     Else
         For lngX = 1 To Len(String1)
             If InStr(String2, Mid$(String1, lngX, 1)) <> 0 Then
                 StringsHaveAMatchingCharacter = True
                 Exit Function
             End If
         Next lngX
     End If

     StringsHaveAMatchingCharacter = False

 End Function
```

I can call this function with commandbutton on form. But how to use specify on my event if function returns "false" or "true" as I want new dialog form to be open if function returns "True" else I want msgbox and cancel opening dialog form.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I understand the problem. You simply call the function and use its return value.

```vb
Private Sub cmdOpenDialog_Click()

    Dim isMatch As Boolean

    isMatch = StringsHaveAMatchingCharacter(Me!Text1.Value, Me!Text2.Value)

    If isMatch Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "myDialog"
    Else
        MsgBox "Nope."
    End If

End Sub
```